# How to get linksta pcie in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e

I'm coding in cpp, and I want to get back linksta whice is including number of lanes and bandwidth.
I know I can get it with regex in lspci -vv, but I perfer an API if someone know any.

Comment: Read the code of `lspci` and do what it does.  Or run `strace lspci -vv` and see what system calls it makes.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27420834/1328439). It doesn't consider the specific attributes you are asking about, but links to `libpci`.

Comment: Also this [short script](https://github.com/joelandman/pcilist) should be helpful. It is actually parsing `lspci -vvvkb`